# EF: Error during seeding "Ambiguous match found." epecially during many to many insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am getting error during seeding which says "Ambiguous match found." especially at the following code:

```
.....
RoleSeeder.GetInitailRole().ForEach(r => context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r));
....
```

My role RoleSeeder class is :

```
public class RoleSeeder
{
    public static List<Role> GetInitailRole()
    {
        return new List<Role>
        {
            new Role {
                Id = (int)RpsActorsRole.SuperAdmin,
                Name = RpsActorsRole.SuperAdmin.ToString(),
                Users = UserSeeder.GetSuperAdminUsers()
            },
            new Role {
                Id = (int)RpsActorsRole.CompanyAdmin,
                Name = RpsActorsRole.CompanyAdmin.ToString(),
                Users = UserSeeder.GetCompanyAdminUsers()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your line of code

```
RoleSeeder.GetInitailRole().ForEach(r => context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r));
```

to this one:

```
RoleSeeder.GetInitailRole().ForEach(r => context.Roles.Add(r));
```